# Can an Azure Pipeline trigger a second pipeline, run as a different user?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm running Azure pipelines on a Windows self-hosted agent. One of my pipelines can do both a 32-bit build and a 64-bit build. I want to use the `matrix` and `maxParallel` capabilities to do both builds at once, on the same agent, to save time.

This isn't possible, because the 32-bit build and the 64-bit build both write to the registry, and whoever gets there second, errors out.

The obvious solution is to get a second Azure VM and run a second self-hosted agent on that VM. But I want to see if I can run the two build tasks as two different users, on the theory that they will then write to their own HKCU and not clobber each other.

This would require the default pipeline to trigger a second pipeline, or perhaps run a template, and run it as a different user.

Can this be done?

OTHER USEFUL INFO:

1. On an Azure DevOps skill-level scale of Beginner-Intermediate-Expert, I'm smack in the middle of Intermediate. Still learning.
2. The build step uses the built-in VSBuild task.

Comment: Each agent can only process one job at a time; that's a fixed constraint you'll have to work with.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind: "one agent, one job". Adding that to the rule of thumb "one agent, one user", prompted by @qbik 's response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger a second pipeline (i.e. by using [Trigger Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks)), but pipelines don't have a concept of running *as a user* - they run *on an agent*. That agent runs as specific user and it would be tricky to try and execute code as a different user.

Running a second self-hosted agent is a good direction. You don't necessarily need another VM - you could run another agent on the same machine, but as a different user, using different work directory.

You could use agent capabilities and [demands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to fine tune which kind of build runs on which agent.

Comment: This would be useful. My VM has enough horsepower to handle multiple agents. 

This is something I want to follow up on. I can create and configure another agent. How do I run it as a different user? (I read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#run-the-agent but didn't see this wrinkle in the docs.)

Comment: If you configure it to run as a service, you've got `--windowsLogonAccount` and `--windowsLogonPassword` arguments: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#windows-only-startup

Comment: Awesome. That'll do it.